# Unable to use CURL to update an empty imagemosaic

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, curl

After creating an empty image mosaic :

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type:application/zip"
--data-binary @/services/GeoServer/data_dir/data/MaltaLab/basic.zip http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/SHAREMED/coveragestores/test_base/file.imagemosaic?configure=none
```

And trying to update it using preexisting folder:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file://services/GeoServer/data_dir/data/CMEMS/WIND/CMEMS-WIND-V-SAT-2021082118.tif" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/SHAREMED/coveragestores/test_base/external.imagemosaic"
```

I get the error :

```
Note : Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
 Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces/SHAREMED/coveragestores/test_base/external.imagemosaic HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 82
>
 upload completely sent off: 82 out of 82 bytes
 Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)
<
Failed to create reader from file:data/SHAREMED/test_base and hints Hints:
  REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@715042ff
System defaults:
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE                 = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@20ff40ee[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@1f443fae
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl
Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
nikola@watercolours:~$
```

Which I do not understand. What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be just missing a / in your file path.

Try

> curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d
> "file:///services/GeoServer/data_dir ...

instead of

> curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d
> "file://services/GeoServer/data_dir ...

Comment: Correct - it was an issue of typing. Specifically the extra "/" was missing. Thank you!